# How to lock orientation for an app in meteor

Tags: android, ios, meteor, build

I want to lock the orientation for the app I'm building in meteor.
The resources suggest installing a cordova plugin but i don't want to do that, there is another way?

Answer (score 3):

You just have to add this line in the mobile-config.js file

```
App.setPreference("orientation", "portrait");
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` for each activity in your **manifest.xml**

**Eg:-**

```
        <activity
            android:name=".activitiesName"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
```